# How can i unscrew free bolt?

Tags: electrical, wood

I have wrongly inserted a nut into a wrong place. Now i want to take them out but drill wont unscrew it as the nut is free, neither would L-key. How can i take it out? [image]

Comment: Have you tried pliers?  It may just work since it is sticking out enough..

Comment: Yes but its too in and damage the wood

Comment: @SDsolar i want to re use it after taking it out from here

Comment: You stick a screwdriver or razor blade under the screw head, and pull up on it while unscrewing. Once you get a little distance, you can stick something thicker/easier to hold in there,

Answer (score 1):

You could try using some wire cutters. Squeeze the wire cutter blades under the head of the bolt. Use a screw gun with the right bit and spin the bolt, at the same time work the wire cutter under the head and use the cutters to help pull up the bolt.

Answer (score 0):

Vice grips would probably work best.  I can't tell how big the bolt is, but the large size vice grips (locking pliers) could be carefully clamped on end and the bolt unscrewed.  Large Vice grips have knurled jaw tips and grip very tightly, enough to crush that bolt head.

Maybe put a few layers of duct tape on the wood to protect it beforehand.  Be careful and the bolt will come out with no damage.

A brute force method, with high wood damage potential would be to file two flats on the bolt head and use a wrench to remove it. One slip filing, even with duct tape and your wood could be gouged.